# Calculate the percentage of accuracy with which user made the assigned sound

Tags: machine-learning, web-applications, nlp, speech-recognition, speech

I want to design a web-app for my cousin who is 2 years of age in which i have implemented a functionality in which when an image is clicked some sound gets played and the user has to make the same sound which gets recorded.
For eg-If i click on image of "Apple" the sound made is "A for Apple".Now the user has to say those words which get recorded.
Now I want to **calculate the percentage of accuracy with which the user spoke**.I want to know how can i know the accuracy percentage.I have not used machine learning or Natural Language Processing earlier so i want some guidance on what should i learn about or ways of implementing this functionality.I need some help on that.
Also use nodejs frameworks quite frequently so is there any module in nodejs with the help of which the above requirement can be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to reach is a quite complex and non-trivial task that can be faced at several levels. First of all, you should answer a question in before for yourself:

**What do you mean with "*accuarcy*"?** Which metric do you want to use for that? Accuracy means to compare a result with its optimum. So what would be the optimum of saying "Apple"?

I think there are several levels on which you could measure speech accuracy:

- On the **audio level**: Here are several correlation metrics that can compute the similarity of two audio files. See e.g. [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar) for more details. SImply said, the idea is directly comparing the audio samples. In your case, you would need a reference audio track that is the "correct" result. The correct time alignment might become a problem though.
- On the level of **speech recognition**: You could use a speech recognizer -- commercial or open source -- and return a string of spoken words. In this case you should think about when the recording is stopped, to limit the record length. Then you have to think about a metric that evaluates the correctness of the transcription. Some that I worked with are [Levensthein-Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [Word-Error-Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_error_rate). Wit these you can compute a similarity.